# Own JSF-components with multiple input-fields

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

The problem I have is much more complex but I try to break it down to a minimal example that demonstrates the main things.

My BeanClass is managing some Entity/POJO where this POJO again contains some other Entities/POJO

```
public class MyEntityA implements Serializable {
   String attributA;
   MyEntityB b;
   // Getter .. Setter
}

public class MyEntityB implements Serializable {
    String attributB
   // Getter .. Setter
}
```

Within my JSF I need input-Fields for all of the attributs like

```
<p:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.entityA.attributeA}" />
<p:inputText value="#{myBean.entityA.b.attributeB}" />
```

Instead of this I marely want to write somethin similar to

```
<my:custom property="#{myBean.entiyA}" />
```

---

With using an own **facelet tag file** I have to assign every single attribute I want to be able to change, so the benefit that I will get is dissatisfying , because I have to touch each of my tags if my EntityClasses change. And that is one point I want to avoid.

---

Using **composite component** I have the problem that this is rendered as a *single component* but that destroys the whole design of my page if I want to use this e.g. in a panelGrid.

---

Is it possible to achieve this with a **Custom Component** and **Tag Handler**? Or are is their even a more simple way? How could a solution for my short example look like with using a Custom Component and Tag Handler?

---

In the very end I have to somehow loop over these components.

```
 <c:forEach var="item" items="#{myBean.entityACollection}">
       <my:custom property="#{item}"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

should be the same as I write anything like

```
 <p:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.firstEntityA.attributeA}" />
 <p:inputText value="#{myBean.firstEntityA.b.attributeB}" />
 <p:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.secondEntityA.attributeA}" />
 <p:inputText value="#{myBean.secondEntityA.b.attributeB}" />
 <p:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.thirdEntityA.attributeA}" />
 <p:inputText value="#{myBean.thirdEntityA.b.attributeB}" />
 ...
```

---

If you need additional information or there are problems with understanding my question please let know!

I am using 
*PrimeFaces 4.0* and
*Mojarra 2.1.26*

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy Is *composite-component* really an appropriate tag for this question? Because as mentioned in my question I was not able to solve my problems with a composite-component, but rather I think I have to write an own *custom component*

Comment: this tag will attract people who could help you, I think that it is appropriate from this perspective.